# Always getting FK value 0 and navigation property null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to create `foreign key relationship using Entity Framework Code first approach`.

I am creating `1-M relation b/w Vehicle and FileUpload` (user can upload multiple images against one vehicle).

**Problem:** I always get `FK value 0` and `Vehicle navigation property null` when saving file information.

**Please help to understand what i am doing wrong?**

Following are model classes with FK relation defined.

**Vehicle model**

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {
        FileUploads = new List<FileUpload>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileUpload> FileUploads { get; set; }

}
```

**File Upload Model**

```
public class FileUpload
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public int Vehicle Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Vehicle Id")]
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Display(Name = "File name")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FileName{ get; set; }

}
```

**My post method inside controller**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
        {
            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
            var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            _saveToDB(postedFile.FileName);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}

private void _saveToDB(string fileName)
{           
    FileUpload data = new FileUpload();
    data.FileName = fileName;
    db.FileUpload.Add(data);   // here data.VehicleId is always 0 and navigation property null. At this stage Vehicle record has been already created in database.
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

data.VehicleId is 0 because data is a local variable you created.

```
FileUpload data = new FileUpload();
```

This is just C# code, and Entity Framework Code First has no knowledge about what VehicleId, these files need to be saved against.

Essentially, you need a VehicleId in your POST input or from the snippet that creates the Vehicle record. (to know the Vehicle againts which these images need to be uploaded)

Once you have the VehicleId, set it on the data object.

```
FileUpload data = new FileUpload();
data.FileName = fileName;
data.VehicleId = vehicleId; // get this from POST input or the snippet that created the Vehicle record.. so vehicle.Id
db.FileUpload.Add(data);   

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: How do i get "get this from POST input or the snippet that created the Vehicle record.. so vehicle.Id"? Also, does navigation property 'Vehicle' is not auto populated?

Comment: The navigation property can be populated only when you retrieve an existing FileUpload entuty from the database.. e.g. var data = db.FileUploads.Include(fu => fu.Vehicle).FirstOrDefault();   // data.Vehicle will be populated in this case.   but in your example above, data is a local variable you are creating. EF has no way of knowing what Vehicle corresponds to it. You have to give it that value to add it to the database. think how would you insert child rows in a database table. you need to know the parent id before you can insert child records. this is similar to that.